# Using android accelerator to calculate an exact relative position of device

Tags: android, filter, 3d, accelerometer, sensormanager

I'm trying to use an android phone's internal sensors as a means of defining a 3D object for use in a video game. I therefore need to create a map of the phone's orientation, and relative location over time. (relative to a starting position) I tried creating a test app which kept a float[] (x,y,z) of a 'current location' and kept adding the data from the sensors to it. But the noise from the sensors just made the current location slowly wobble off the grid I was using to visualize the feedback. I've looked through filters online, and all explanations are just confusing. Is there anyway to get a cleaner output from the sensors? Is there a better way of tracking the phone's exact relative location?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to accurately track a device's position with a typical phone or tablet. In theory, you can use a device's internal sensors to measure its acceleration in each axis. In theory, you integrate acceleration once to obtain speed and once more to obtain change in position. Thus, in theory, you should be able to calculate a device's position relative to its starting location. HOWEVER, in practice, things don't work out so well.

A device's sensors are not perfect and contain small errors. Integrating these small errors twice turns them into large errors. These large errors accumulate and end up making your calculations useless.

Take a look at [Project Tango](https://www.google.com/atap/project-tango/), which contains a bunch of fancy sensors and algorithms to implement 6 DOF tracking. This device was built by a research team and is still a work in progress, so keep in mind that it's a tough problem.